# An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time Exception occurs on calling WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, asynchronous, exception

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 project I'm calling a web service for login authentication. But it throws an exception:

[image: Asynchronous Exception]

Exception Details:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: How is the controller action declared? Is it `async`?

Comment: you can also create another thread for time consuming process :) . async methods also create another thread internally

Comment: Make sure the Controller returns an async Task or void and call await on the async method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that your Controller method returns an async Task.

```
public class ServiceController : Controller 
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {       
        var service = new Service();
        await service.CallMethodAsync();    
        return View();
    }
}
```

Basically, the documentation is written in a way where they believe you are only using ASP.NET WebForms, however obviously you can use this in MVC applications too, so their documentation needs to be updated.

Comment: Task loss HttpContext it is a big problem

Comment: I tried this, but the compiler complained with, *"The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator"* See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74722945/153923

Answer (score 7):

You are calling an ASYNC method therefore you must add Async="true" inside your page declaration <%@ Page .....%>.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thank you for saving my weekend :D

Comment: Does not works when performing async in masterpage, can you tell one for that..

Comment: @raw_hitt I think that's because the MasterPage is a control of the page and not a page itself.