# MSTest failed to publish test result with error An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time

Tags: tfs, mstest

TFS and VS version is 2013.

Command:

MSTest.exe   /publish:CollectionURL /teamproject:Project /publishbuild:"BuildId"  /PublishResultsFile:"ResultFile"  /flavor:debug /platform:"Any CPU"

Error:

Waiting to publish...

Publishing results of resultfile to http://[collection]...

..An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
Publish failed or canceled

Comment: Please format your code with code blocks.

Comment: The version is too old to be officially supported. We recommend to upgrade the latest version of Azure DevOps server and Visual Studio. Anyway, please check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101708/an-asynchronous-operation-cannot-be-started-at-this-time-exception-occurs-on-cal