# Can ASP.NET MVC 5 use Async methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

ASP.NET MVC 5 with .NET Framework v4.5.2

I've got a large, existing project that I have been assigned. Some parts of it take a really long time, so I wanted to see about putting some of these "new to me" asynchronous calls in the code.

But, after looking at the examples, I don't know if what I have can do that.

Take this typical method on my controller:

```cs
public ActionResult DealerSelect()
{
    var model = RetailActivityModelData.GetCurrentDealers(null, ViewBag.Library);
    return View(model);
}
```

I don't really understand how to turn that into an asynchronous call unless I did something like this:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> DealerSelect()
{
    var model = await RetailActivityModelData.GetCurrentDealers(null, ViewBag.Library);
    return View(model);
}
```

But the compiler complains with:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator

[image: compiler]

I'm not sure how to change the return type without destroying the View model.

So, I went into the `GetCurrentDealers` method to make a basic BackgroundWorker call:

```cs
public static DealerModel GetCurrentDealers(DealerModel model, string library)
{
    m_library = library;
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new AdminCurrentDealerModel();
    }
    using (var bg = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        bg.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // fill 3 DataTables with calls to database
        };
        bg.ProgressChanged += delegate (object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // add data from DataTables to model
        };
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            mre.Set();
        };
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
        if (bg.IsBusy)
        {
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

It compiles just fine, but crashes as soon as `bg.RunWorkerAsync()` is called:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.'

This is an ASP.NET MVC Razor page, so it doesn't really have that `<%@ Page Async="true" %>` part.

Razor page:

```cs
@model Manufacturer.Models.CurrentDealerModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DealerSelect";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ConsoleLayout.cshtml";
}
    <style>
        #DealerInfoGrid{
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
    </style>
<h2>Dealer Select</h2>
@{ 
    var dealers = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var dealer in Model.Dealers) {
        dealers.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = dealer.DealerNumber, Text = dealer.DealerName });
    }
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Dealer.DealerNumber,dealers);
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }

@{ 
    if (Model.DealershipInfo != null)
    {
    <div id="DealerInfoGrid">
        <div>
            <label>Region: @Model.DealershipInfo.Region</label><br />
            <label>Name: @Model.DealershipInfo.Name</label><br />
            <label>Address: @Model.DealershipInfo.Address</label><br />

        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Dealer No: @Model.DealershipInfo.DealerNumber</label><br />
            <label>Sales Phone: @Model.DealershipInfo.SalesPHNumber</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
    if(Model.Contacts.Count() >0)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Contact Name</td>
                <td>Digital Contact</td>
                <td>Phone Type</td>
                <td>Phone Number</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @contact.Title
            </td>
            <td>
                @contact.ContactName
            </td>
            <td>
                @contact.DigitalContact
            </td>
            <td>
                @contact.PhoneType
            </td>
            <td>
                @contact.PhoneNumber
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
    if(@Model.DirectContacts.Count >0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.DirectContacts.Count(); i++)
        {
<label>@Model.DirectContacts[i].Department: <a href="mailto:@(Model.DirectContacts[i].Href)">@Model.DirectContacts[i].Href</a></label><br />
        }
    }
}
```

Can I even do incremental asynchronous development on this project, or does the whole thing need to be converted to one that uses Tasks?

### Edit: Solved

I wound up going with a hybrid approach that combined the 2 answers that I received. From what Stephen wrote, I abandoned the `BackgroundWorker` control that I was familiar with, and like Ronnie pointed out, I needed to make the call to `GetCurrentDealers` asynchronous as well.

```cs
public static async Task<CurrentDealerModel> GetCurrentDealersAsync(CurrentDealerModel model)
{
    bool includeDealerDetails = true;
    if (model == null)
    {
        includeDealerDetails = false;
        model = new CurrentDealerModel();
    }
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(m_conStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var taskGetDealerInfo = GetDealerInfoAsync(conn);
        var taskGetDealershipInfo = GetDealershipInfoAsync(conn);
        var taskGetContacts = GetContactsAsync(conn);
        var taskGetDirectContacts = GetDirectContactsAsync(conn);
        tasks.Add(taskGetDealerInfo);
        if (includeDealerDetails)
        {
            tasks.Add(taskGetDealershipInfo);
            tasks.Add(taskGetContacts);
            tasks.Add(taskGetDirectContacts);
        }
        while (0 < tasks.Count)
        {
            var done = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            if (!done.IsFaulted)
            {
                if (done == taskGetDealerInfo)
                {
                    model.Dealers = taskGetDealerInfo.Result;
                }
                else if (done == taskGetDealershipInfo)
                {
                    model.AllDealerships = taskGetDealershipInfo.Result;
                }
                else if (done == taskGetContacts)
                {
                    model.Contacts = taskGetContacts.Result;
                }
                else if (done == taskGetDirectContacts)
                {
                    model.DirectContacts = taskGetDirectContacts.Result;
                }
            } else
            {
                throw done.Exception.Flatten();
            }
            tasks.Remove(done);
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Each of the tasks are small and basic, like this one:

```cs
private static async Task<DealerSelectInfoList> GetDealerInfoAsync(OleDbConnection openConnection)
{
    var result = new DealerSelectInfoList();
    var table = new DataTable();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("", openConnection))
    {
        cmd.CommandText = $@"
SELECT DISTINCT(DADNAM) AS DADNAM, DADLRN, DASRGN
FROM {m_library}.DLRINVAPF
WHERE DASRGN IN(SELECT RGNAMEM FROM {m_library}.REGIONPF) 
ORDER BY DADNAM ASC for read only with UR";
        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        table.Load(reader);
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(new DealerSelectInfo()
        {
            DealerName = $"{row["DADNAM"]}".Trim(),
            DealerNumber = $"{row["DADLRN"]}".Trim(),
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method GetCurrentDealers() isn't async so you can't call it with await.

### Edit

#### Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DealerSelect()
{
    var model = await RetailActivityModelData.GetCurrentDealersAsync(null, ViewBag.Library);
    return View(model);
}
```

#### GetCurrentDealersAsync()

```
public static async Task<DealerModel> GetCurrentDealersAsync(DealerModel model, string library)
{
    m_library = library;
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new AdminCurrentDealerModel();
    }
    using (var bg = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        bg.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // fill 3 DataTables with calls to database
        };
        bg.ProgressChanged += delegate (object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // add data from DataTables to model
        };
        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            mre.Set();
        };
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
        if (bg.IsBusy)
        {
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Comment: I understand that. I'm trying to find out how to get it done. If I write `GetCurrentDealers()` as async, then I cannot call it from the `public ActionResult DealerSelect()`

Comment: you could make the controller async: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentDealers()`

Comment: That sounds promising, but how would I modify the return type `return View(model);`? If I modify it to return `Task<IActionResult>`, the Razor ASP.NET page doesn't know how to process the results.

Comment: That's weird. Normally you can just return the View as always, if the endpoint is async. I'll edit the answer and add the code how I would do it.

Comment: Can you show me your razor page?

Comment: I added the Razor page in the original question. I tried something similar to what your edited answer says by making it async and returning the view, but I get a CS1983 error saying that `The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable, or IAsyncEnumerator`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert my view into this "task-like type".

Comment: Did you make the endpoint async like I did in the code I sent you? Because if you return a task of an IActionResult this shouldn't happen, because you're returning a task

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but then I can't return the View to the Razor page. So far, if I try returning something like `Task<model>`, the Razor page just shows no data. No error, and no data.

Answer (score 1):

> ASP.NET MVC 5 with .NET Framework v4.5.2

Please see my article [Introduction to Async on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). In particular, ensure you have `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set correctly to avoid the server-side "quirks mode".

> make a basic BackgroundWorker call

You should never use `BackgroundWorker` on ASP.NET. And almost never use `Task.Run` (or `StartNew`). You cannot "make something asynchronous" this way.

The exception you encounter is a "safety net" exception.

> I don't really understand how to turn that into an asynchronous call

Don't start at the controllers. That's actually the *opposite* of the easiest way to do it. Instead, start with the lowest-level code you have that performs any I/O. E.g., database queries or calls to external APIs. One at a time, make *those* asynchronous (using `await` to call asynchronous APIs), and then allow the `async`/`await` usage to grow out from there. Eventually, your controller methods will become `async` as the *last* step of this process.

> Can I even do incremental asynchronous development on this project, or does the whole thing need to be converted to one that uses Tasks?

As you're converting to `async`, you may find it useful to (temporarily) have two copies of the code: one async (used by code that is already converted) and one sync (used by unconverted code). This is fine if you're doing an conversion-to-async that won't be interrupted by other feature work. If you need longer-term support for both async and sync code, then you can use the [boolean argument hack described in my Brownfield Async article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#the-flag-argument-hack) (or if you want a more modern/complex solution, use [generic code generation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/10/modern-csharp-techniques-3-generic-code-generation.html#:%7E:text=Replacing%20Constant%20Arguments) as described on my blog).

Comment: I'm a contractor with 6 months to resolve bugs and try to make their website faster. I am not authorized to rebuild their whole website. This would be easy with WinForms. It sounds like there is no way to tweak `public ActionResult DealerSelect()` to an asynchronous method.

Comment: 1) "async" does not necessarily mean "faster"; `async` allows you to handle more simultaneous requests, but each request takes the same amount of time. 2) This would not be easy with WinForms.
If you're looking for quick performance wins, my experience is that fixing inefficient SQL statements is usually the best bang for the buck.

Comment: There are 3 database calls that collect information about the models. 1) Dealerships, 2) Contacts, and 3) Products. I can call each one, pass the table in the `ProgressChangedEventArgs`, make the next call in the thread while processing the results. I've done that often. The company still hasn't figured out how to get me access to the IBM AS400 database, and it's been a month.